# how to know whether a subset of euclidean space is path connected or not?(2)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

I am asked whether $X=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2−z^2=1\}\subset \mathbb{R^3}$,is path connected or not.

i just know that $X$ is a closed subset.how can i answer this question?

is there any hint?

i asked a similar question,but that answer couldn't be generalized to this case.

thank you very much.

Comment: It might help to [know what it looks like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2-z%5E2%3D1). Once you do, it should help you figure out what a path between two points might look like. Another thing you might consider is describing such a path using cylindrical coordinates.